# Increase link length in node-link graph using d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg, visualization

How can I increase the link length of a force graph. My code is written below. What should I change?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  // Add lines for every link in the dataset
  var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });

  // Add circles for every node in the dataset
  var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    //   .style("fill", function (d) { return '#1f77b4'; })
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return '#aec7e8';
    })
    // .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended)
    );

  // Basic tooltips
  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  // Attach nodes to the simulation, add listener on the "tick" event
  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  // Associate the lines with the "link" force
  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links)
</script>
```

I wanted the visualization to be seen clearly by reader. This is because the visualization of the node is very closed to each other.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. Are you able to produce the force graph with the above code?

Comment: I try to display my full html code but stackoverflow gives out an error comment

Comment: It seems you have found your answer below. Please mark the solution provided below as the answer and remember to up vote it, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `.strength()` of `d3.forceManyBody()` to larger values

---

```
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-3));
```

[image]

---

```
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-30));
```

[image]

Comment: @NurHidayah glad to help

Comment: Do you know how can i highlight the nodes which is only connected to a specific node? I have tried some code but it does not worked.

Comment: @NurHidayah yes, but you need to add this information to a nodes

Comment: @NurHidayah yes, info about node need to be highligted, look at snippet here, i've corrected it just now for show your case https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/969307/188366